# OpenShift rhc fail on setup

Tags: ruby, openshift, openshift-client-tools

I'm new with OpenShift, I have a Windows 10 (x86) machine, I'm trying to setup the rhc, but show me that message:

`rhc setup
D:/Herramientas/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext kernel_require.rb:54:in require': cannot load such file -- dl/import (LoadError)
        from D:/Herramientas/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:inrequire'
        from D:/Herramientas/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/pageant.rb:1:in <top (required)>'
        from D:/Herramientas/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:inrequire'
        from D:/Herramientas/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in require'
        from D:/Herramientas/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/agent/socket.rb:5:in'
        from D:/Herramientas/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in require'
        from D:/Herramientas/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:inrequire'
        from D:/Herramientas/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/agent.rb:22:in <top (required)>'
        from D:/Herramientas/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:inrequire'
        from D:/Herramientas/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in require'
        from D:/Herramientas/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/key_manager.rb:4:in'
        from D:/Herramientas/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in require'
        from D:/Herramientas/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:inrequire'
        from D:/Herramientas/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:4:in <top (required)>'
        from D:/Herramientas/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:inrequire'
        from D:/Herramientas/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in require'
        from D:/Herramientas/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh.rb:11:in'
        from D:/Herramientas/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in require'
        from D:/Herramientas/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:inrequire'
        from D:/Herramientas/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/ssh_helpers.rb:18:in <top (required)>'
        from D:/Herramientas/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/wizard.rb:77:in'
        from D:/Herramientas/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/wizard.rb:7:in <module:RHC>'
        from D:/Herramientas/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/wizard.rb:6:in'
        from D:/Herramientas/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in require'
        from D:/Herramientas/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:inrequire'
        from D:/Herramientas/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/commands/base.rb:4:in <top (required)>'
        from D:/Herramientas/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/commands/account.rb:2:in'
        from D:/Herramientas/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/commands/account.rb:1:in <top (required)>'
        from D:/Herramientas/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:inrequire'
        from D:/Herramientas/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in require'
        from D:/Herramientas/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/commands.rb:189:inblock in load'
        from D:/Herramientas/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/commands.rb:188:in each'
        from D:/Herramientas/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/commands.rb:188:inload'
        from D:/Herramientas/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.38.4/lib/rhc/cli.rb:36:in start'
        from D:/Herramientas/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.38.4/bin/rhc:20:in'
        from D:/Herramientas/Ruby/bin/rhc:23:in load'
        from D:/Herramientas/Ruby/bin/rhc:23:in'`

Anybody can help me?

Comment: dl has been removed from later version of ruby... it is advised to use fiddle instead ... https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_2_0/NEWS#L148-L149

Comment: fiddle is used on net-ssh version 3.* onwards ... simple hack to fix this -> http://stackoverflow.com/q/31906673/2382629

Answer (score 0):

you might want to check the versions of ruby and git. Or just [reinstall](https://developers.openshift.com/en/getting-started-windows.html) them.

`ruby -v`

`git --version`

if your console cannot recognize the commands, you need to check your environment variable and add ruby and git to the env.

[Installing Git in PATH with GitHub client for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26620312/installing-git-in-path-with-github-client-for-windows)

[How do I add Ruby to the PATH variable on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26947427/how-do-i-add-ruby-to-the-path-variable-on-windows)

Reinstall rhc using following command
`gem install rhc`

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answer.

My ruby version: `ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [i386-mingw32]`

My git version: `git version 2.6.3.windows.1`

This was got with commands mentioned, those programms was installed before rhc such as say tutorial.

When I run the `rhc setup` then show me the error posted above.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently RHC for windows functionality requires an older version of Ruby.  **You want to use Ruby 1.9.3** ( and its latest supplement) .  If you go to the normal [Ruby download site](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/) you will want to select the [Archives>>](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/) link.  You will probably have to manually update your systems environment path variable to place your Ruby path there (and reboot your system) before you can see results. (My install is at `C:\Ruby193\bin`) I had terrible troubles attempting to use RHC on multiple windows machines until I reverted to that version of Ruby.

Have fun with the OpenShift stuff.