# R: shell command - wayback-machine-downloader is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: ruby, r, windows, rubygems, system

I'm trying to run a ruby gem command called [wayback-machine-downloader](https://github.com/hartator/wayback-machine-downloader) from R using the shell command:

```
shell(ruby_call)
```

but I get the following error messages:

> 'wayback_machine_downloader' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
>
> Warning messages:
>
> 1: running command 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c wayback_machine_downloader https://undergroundreptiles.com/ --directory C:/Users/oliver/websites/underground_19981212033710 --from 19981212033710 --concurrency 200' had status 1
>
> 2: In shell(ruby_call) :
>     'wayback_machine_downloader https://undergroundreptiles.com/ --directory C:/Users/oliver/websites/underground_19981212033710 --from 19981212033710 --concurrency 200' execution failed with error code 1`

When I run the exact same code directly from the command line it runs perfectly. Is there some setting I need to change in R/RStudio?

I also tried the system command, but that doesn't work either:

```
system(ruby_call)
```

> Warning message:
>
> running command 'wayback_machine_downloader https://undergroundreptiles.com/ --directory C:/Users/oliver/websites/underground_19981212033710 --from 19981212033710 --concurrency 200' had status 127 `

Answer (score 0):

adding ruby to path before running will fix it:

`set PATH=C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/bin;%PATH%`

[How do I add Ruby to the PATH variable on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26947427/how-do-i-add-ruby-to-the-path-variable-on-windows)