# Installing gems fails with timeout error

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to install sass gem. Installing fails with timeout error.

[image: Time out error]
***Error: Could not find a valid gem 'sass' ()=0), here is why: Unable to download data from https ://rubygems.org/ - timed out (https: //api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)***

I tried to change my gem source from https ://rubygems.org/ to http ://rubygems.org/. When I'm trying to change gem source it fails with this error:

[image: this error]

***Error: While executing gem ... (Errno::ENOENT) No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - H:/.gemrc***

Can you help me with this issue?

(I've inserted spaces in links because I have less then 10 reputation)

Comment: Can you connect manually to `rubygems.org` from the server? Why are you trying to remove it as a source? Do you have an alternate source?

Comment: Also, please post your errors as (nicely formatted) **text**, not images (or links to images).

Comment: @TomLord What do you mean by "connect manually"? I could load the site using browser. Is it an answer to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say without some more info but judging from your second error - it may be that your `PATH` environment variable may be set incorrectly.

Looks like ruby is trying to read from the `H:/` drive - is that where the interpreter is installed?. This may help [[How do I add Ruby to the PATH variable on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26947427/how-do-i-add-ruby-to-the-path-variable-on-windows])

Comment: Here is my PATH variable [PATH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIWvt.png). And my [gem env](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLqou.png)

Answer (score 1):

You may be experiencing the issue with IPv6 that some others are, including myself. Here is another topic about it: [gem cannot access rubygems.org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49800432/gem-cannot-access-rubygems-org/50349235#50349235)

And numerous threads on rubygems.org: http://help.rubygems.org/discussions/problems/31074-timeout-error