# Error :: installing Rails on windows machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, git-bash

I tried installing ruby on my laptop with the configuration shown below:

[image: conf]

- I followed the installation steps using this [medium blog](https://medium.com/ruby-on-rails-web-application-development/how-to-install-rubyonrails-on-windows-7-8-10-complete-tutorial-2017-fc95720ee059)
- The environment variables were set up successfully, which I confirmed using the following commands:

  `ruby --version` ~ ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x64-mingw32]

  `gem --version` ~ 2.7.6
- Also, I installed a few gems which I was required such as:

  `gem install make`

  `gem install pepipost_gem` and few others.

The problem here is when I tried installing rails using the below command:

`gem install rails`

Some weird error arises can anyone help me in resolving this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I was able to resolve the error.

The issue was with the version where I was using `ruby ~ 2.5.1p57` and downloaded devkit separately due to which some misconfiguration occurred.

In order to resolve the error in dept, I reinstalled ruby with devkit and followed below steps

- Remove previously installed ruby (Uninstalled using windows uninstaller)
- Removed MSYS2 installer (devkit for ruby which I installed separately)
- Installed [Ruby+Devkit 2.4.X as x64](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller2/releases/download/rubyinstaller-2.4.4-2/rubyinstaller-devkit-2.4.4-2-x64.exe) from [Ruby](https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/) (Stable for the users who is new to ruby)
- Once Installation is done set your [environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26947427/how-do-i-add-ruby-to-the-path-variable-on-windows) variable in order to access globally.
- check

  `ruby --version` ~ ruby 2.4.4p296 (2018-03-28 revision 63013) [x64-mingw32]

  `gem --version` ~ 2.6.14.1
- Installing rails Successfully

  `gem install rails`

  [few lines of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnuAS.png)